# Rule of thumb for Module count in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've started work on a new project, and I decided to also learn something new along the way. So, I forked [a project on github, that claims to be done with best practices in mind](https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-). The thing that I am wondering about, is this:

**Is there a rule of thumb, how many modules should I have?** And by modules I mean parts of the application that have significantly different features from another part. Eg. `admin`,`default`,`auth` modules.

How many is too many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am of the view that the right number of modules depends on the type of application that you create.
For example, you want a client side and an admin? then the number you are looking for is 2!
I do not think there is a number that indicates that they are too much!
Then I finally tastes. For example I do not like the auth module separately. I prefer to write an ad hoc form, if required.